# Many-Many JPA not working

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

This is the problem, I have done the join table and SQL and when I query the database, I get the result I want. However, when I try to map it in java via the JPA, I get the exception that my list cannot be found/mapped

This is the working SQL between two tables:

```
select f.*, b.*  
from fuses f
join fusesdistributionboard fbt on f.id = fbt.fuse_id
join distributionboard b on b.id = fbt.board_id
```

Which yields results as I wanted them.

This are my models in java:

Fuse model JPA part:

```
 @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "fusesdistributionboard", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "fuse_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), 
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "board_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
public List<Fuse> fuseList;
```

Distribution Board JPA part:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="fuseList",fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
public List<DistributionBoard> boardList;
```

Trying to run it with this code:

```
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = 
Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("testjpa");
EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
Fuse f = em.find(Fuse.class, 10);
System.out.println("Fuse 10 used in: : " + f.getFuseList());
em.close();
entityManagerFactory.close();
```

Exception thrown:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: hr.croz.bspoljaric.model.DistributionBoard.fuseList in hr.croz.bspoljaric.model.DistributionBoard.boardList
```

Edit:

Entity full part of class DistributionBoard.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "distributionBoard", schema = "bornasite")
public class DistributionBoard {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@NotNull
private int id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "investor")
private String investor;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy="fuseList",fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
public List<DistributionBoard> boardList;
```

Fuse Entity part:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "fuses", schema = "bornasite")
public class Fuse {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@NotNull
private int id;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "type")
private String type;

@Column(name = "created_at")
private String dateCreated;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "characteristics")
private String characteristics;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "quantity")
private int quantity;

@NotNull
@OneToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "manufacturer_id")
private Manufacturer manufacturer;

 @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "fusesdistributionboard", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "fuse_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), 
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "board_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
public List<Fuse> fuseList;
```

Comment: Can you add the classes to your question?

Comment: what are the entity class names

Comment: Added to the Edit, you can have a look now

Comment: In the Fuse class you should have a list of DistributionBoards, not a list of Fuses. And in the DIstributionBoard you should have a list of Fuse. So you will have a fuseList property in your DIstributionBoard (what is logic) and this exception won't happen.